# Password protect user viewing in WP or Joomla

Tags: joomla, wordpress, restriction, user-profile

I was hoping if anyone know an extension or plugin for either WordPress or Joomla (preferably), that can restrict unauthorized visitors from viewing full profile information?

What I am trying to achieve is something like this: http://keepmesafeid.com/lost.php?id=1ba0846587744383fa518b7e642ff632

Visitors can't view the full profile information before entering a password that is associated to the profile.
Each profile will have a unique password associated that the visitor needs to enter, before the visitor can see full profile info.

I hope some of you guys can help me out here.

Comment: Joomla **or** Wordpress? Which one specifically? They are 2 different CMS's

Comment: I know they are two different CMS :)
I prefer Joomla, but if there is a nice plugin that works out of the box with WordPress, then that is alright too.